# How to get entire xml as string from stream using SAX parser?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

i know you can convert `InputStream` to string using something like :

```
 public static String convertStreamToString(ServletInputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

Which is fine, however my input stream is an xml I parse using SAX Parser, and I was wondering if there is an faster way to get the XML as string, since the parser already loops through the stream.

I can get it to work by  concating the string in all the events,but I was wondering if there's a faster/built in way to do so, since this code is really performance-sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use SAX, there doesn't seem to be a built-in way, see [Echoing an XML File with the SAX Parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPSAX3.html). Or consider using [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) if you can.